# Catch a #NAME error

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, is it possible to "catch" a `#NAME` error?

**Example**

I want a cell to display "YES" if a function is available, and "NO" if it is not.

At first I tried: `=IF(MYFUNCTION(), "YES", "NO")`, but this returns a `#NAME` error instead of "NO".

Then I tried: `=IFERROR(MYFUNCTION(), "NO", "YES")`, but this returns `#N/A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the iferror function

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en

documentation is there

so syntax would be IFERROR(IF(MYFUNCTION(), "YES", "NO"),"NO")

which if an error gets reached in the IF statement then the exception throws a NO The key mistake you used is that iferror takes two arguments and you passed it three so pas the intitial conditional as first argument and the result iferror as second

Now you need the MYFUnction to return a boolean

IF(ISERROR(MYFUNCTION(),FALSE)<>"FALSE","YES","NO")

this should work

Comment: Seems to always return "NO".  Good to know IFERROR only takes 2 arguments though, thank you :)

Comment: If it always returns no then your always throwing an error.. the function MYFUNCTION needs to also return boolean true or false so make sure that your initially conditional statement can evaluate to this so Ill edit my response you might need to lookup the not equals syntax it might be <> or !=

Comment: Also obviously pass your function a value or else your just referencing an empty call to a function